# Generate DENSE_RANK() without using order by clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, window-functions

I am total new to `SQL Server`, can anyone guide me on my query it will very helpful for me.

I need to generate rank like in this example:

```
Report No               Rank 
----------------------------
18  3229                 1
89-0119-87               2
180261292                3
180261292                3
18  3107                 4
18A 7     A06            5
T18002415                6
T18002415                6
T18002415                6
0000000018-519           7
0000000018-519           7
0000000018-519           7
0000000018-519           7
0000000018-655           8
000000018-1002           9
000000018-1002           9
000000018-1002           9
000000018-5712           10
```

If I am generating rank using

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ReportNo DESC)
```

then I'm not getting the required output. Can you please guide me. How can I generate rank as in the above example?

Comment: Please explain logic. Why `89-0119-87` is between `18  3229` and `180261292`

Comment: Are you try my Answer. IS it help or you need anything else?

Comment: Data does not have an order. You can't expect it to be returned in the same order unless you specify an order by -- so trying to implement a rank without order by doesn't make sense.

Comment: @uzi  there is no logic for this type of report no, I am getting Data from different  site

Comment: If you cannot find something sensible to put in an `ORDER BY` clause to generate the output you're looking for, then your requirement isn't sensible - either you're lacking the data that is required to populate that `ORDER BY` or you're expecting the server to magically "know what I mean" when you can't articulate it yourself into the `ORDER BY` clause. An `ORDER BY` clause tricked into accepting a constant (As Dinesh's answer shows) is just throwing your hands up and *hoping* that the server will produce something that sometimes produces results that are pleasing to you.

Comment: If this order is *how the rows came in*, you should add a column `InsertDateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL` with a default constrain setting this to `SYSUTCDATETIME()`. Then you can use this column to reflect the *natural order*. But you must set these values for existing rows according to some logic you have to define. Otherwise it's - again - random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(Report_No VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('18  3229')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('89-0119-87')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('180261292')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('180261292')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('18  3107')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('18A 7     A06')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('T18002415')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('T18002415')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('T18002415')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('0000000018-519')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('0000000018-519')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('0000000018-519')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('0000000018-519')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('0000000018-655')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('000000018-1002')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('000000018-1002')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('000000018-1002')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('000000018-5712')

SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
INTO #temp
FROM @Tab T1

SELECT T1.Report_No
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Report_No = T2.Report_No THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY T1.rn)[Rank]
FROM #temp T1
LEFT JOIN #temp T2 ON T1.rn = T2.rn+1

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Output:**

```
Report_No       Rank
18  3229        1
89-0119-87      2
180261292       3
180261292       3
18  3107        4
18A 7     A06   5
T18002415       6
T18002415       6
T18002415       6
0000000018-519  7
0000000018-519  7
0000000018-519  7
0000000018-519  7
0000000018-655  8
000000018-1002  9
000000018-1002  9
000000018-1002  9
000000018-5712  10
```

Comment: @PawanKumar, Try the Updated answer.

Comment: @DineshDB I have try your Solution and it is working grate, Thanks But it i have large volume no of data for that it is Increase query execution time by more then 5 sec you have any idea about that

Comment: @ParitaNavadiya, I can Understand. But your table don't have any column to order, so we have no way. If any columns exists for ordering, it should be possible.

Comment: @DineshDB My Output table is ordering by ID field

Comment: `ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)` is basically tricking the optimizer into accepting a query that it should usually reject (compare with `ORDER BY NULL` which will be rejected). The whole thing is non-deterministic because of this and so whilst at *times* it may appear to "work" it's just programming by coincidence.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Thanks for the suggestion. I can't found any more solution for the above problem. Suggestions are welcome for the above case instead of downvotes...:-)

Comment: @DineshDB The point is: **There is no solution!** Your suggestion is absolutely dangerous, as it gives the feeling to work correctly, but **there is no guarantee, that a later call will return in the same order**. This answer leads poor noobs on slick ice. This is not a *solution*... I'll vote it down to reflect this.

Comment: @ParitaNavadiya Please read the comments. Although this might work, this is random - nothing more...

Answer (score 3):

I could not see the logic of how Report No is ordered. As it's custom order, create `anotherTable` (temp table or table variable) containing required order `Report No` , `Rank`.

```
Report No           Rank 
18  3229                 1
89-0119-87               2
180261292                3
18  3107                 4
18A 7     A06            5
T18002415                6
0000000018-519           7
0000000018-655           8
000000018-1002           9
000000018-5712           10
```

Then

```
SELECT thisTable.ReportNo, anotherTable.[Rank]
FROM thisTable
INNER JOIN anotherTable ON thisTable.ReportNo = anotherTable.ReportNo
```

Comment: I voted this up (as it is a solution for the issue), but it would be easier to add this sorting column to the table directly - probably... :-D

Comment: @Partita, Can you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use group by:

```
WITH data as (
    SELECT '18  3229' col1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '89-0119-87' UNION ALL
    SELECT '180261292' UNION ALL
    SELECT '180261292' UNION ALL
    SELECT '18  3107' UNION ALL
    SELECT '18A 7     A06' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18002415' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18002415' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18002415' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000000018-519' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000000018-519' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000000018-519' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000000018-519' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000000018-655' UNION ALL
    SELECT '000000018-1002' UNION ALL
    SELECT '000000018-1002' UNION ALL
    SELECT '000000018-1002' UNION ALL
    SELECT '000000018-5712'), 
data_with_rownumber as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) rownum from data
), grouped as (
    SELECT col1, min(rownum) rank from data_with_rownumber group by col1)
select d.col1, DENSE_RANK() over (order by rank) from data d inner join grouped gr on d.col1 = gr.col1
```